# Dealing with search query and action

Tags: php

I did a search feature that will enable users to search and see result from database.

First - I want to transfer the search query (What the user searched for) into the search action (searchact.php)

When A user fills the input field below (form) and hit search...

```
<form action="searchact.php" class=" form-inline" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="word" class="form-control" placeholder="House key word">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="location" class="form-control">
            <option value="Bosso">Bosso Campus</option>
            <option value="GK">Gidan Kwano Campus (GK)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="price" class="form-control">
            <option>10-49k</option>
            <option>50-99k</option>
            <option selected>100-149k</option>
            <option>150-199k</option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Search...">
</form>
```

I want the next page url (searchact.php) to be something like

> wwww.test.com/searchact.php?**q=word&location=Bosso&price=10-49k**

This is searchact.php

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"])
{
$word = $_POST["word"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (word,location,price) VALUES (:word,:location,:price)";
        $q = $connecDB->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':word'=>$word, ':location'=>$location, ':price'=>$price));
if($q)
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM house WHERE location LIKE :location AND tag LIKE :info AND range LIKE :range order by id desc LIMIT 10";
$stmt = $connecDB->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':info', '%' . $word . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':location', '%' . $location . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':range', '%' . $price . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $result as $row ) {
$hid=$row["id"];
$name=$row["name"];
?>
<!--Some Html-->
<?php
}} 
else {
echo 'No result found';
}
}}
?>
```

2nd - How do I make sure that a user actually searched for something without manually visiting "searchact.php"

Like.. How do I redirect a user to an error page when they just visit the searchact.php without inputing any search query.

Comment: You should use method="get" on your form then. And check if $_GET parameters are present in the request in your searchact.php file. Like $_GET['price'], etc.

Comment: Oh! GET method should do the trick. I forgot about it. Sorry!! Stupid Question.